# is there any way to check if a line output of LSD is vertical or horizontal

Tags: python, opencv, math, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I am using LSD: LineSegmentDetector in python and OpenCV, now the problem is I want to count num of horizontal lines detected and number of vertical lines detected.

```
img = cv2.imread("test/images.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 100, 200, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
linesL = lsd(gray)
for line in linesL:
    x1, y1, x2, y2, width = map(int,line)
    length = line_length(x1,y1,x2,y2)
    if line[-1]<3:
        lines_img = cv2.line(img, (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (0,0,0),1)
show_img(lines_img,"FLD")
```

[image: Output]

Lines Array [[x1,y1,x2,y2,width],....]

I have tried morphological operations and houghlinesP as well but they aren't performing well.

Comment: You can get the slope of each line and set a threshold. If the slope satisfies the threshold it is vertical. Otherwise it's horizontal.

Comment: I tried this approach but it didn't work out for me

Comment: lets assume we have 2 coordinates (20,40),(22.5,10.5)
then m  = -11.8, its a vertical line but acc to below logic its horizontal
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/md6buy4efz

Comment: Angle between your line segment an vector (1,0). Read about aran2 or play with simple cosine angle measurement and multiples of pi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use slope for this problem. We know the the slope of a line in angles would be the `arctan` of the ration of difference of `y`s and `x`s

```
slope_as_angle = atan((y1 - y2) / (x1 - x2))
```

It's a good practice to use `atan2` instead of `atan`. and for simplicity let's use degrees instead of radians:

```
slope_as_angle = math.degrees(math.atan2((y1 - y2), (x1 - x2)))
```

Now let's see how lines would look like for different slope angles:

```
for i in range(0, 360, 20):
    x = 10 * math.cos(math.radians(i))
    y = 10 * math.sin(math.radians(i))
    spl = math.degrees(math.atan2(y - 0, x - 0)) % 360

    plt.plot([0, x], [0, y], label=str(i))

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Please notice we are getting slope angles for all lines between (0, 0) and (`cos`, `sin`) (See: [Cartesian to Polar](https://www.omnicalculator.com/math/cartesian-to-polar)) for each `20 degrees`.

[image: Slopes for all lines of each 20 degrees]

Now we need a logic to understand if a line is vertical or horizontal by given slope angle:

### Horizontal

I would say each line with slope angles between [160, 200] or bigger then 340 or smaller then 20 is horizontal.

```
if 160 < angle < 200 or 340 < angle or angle < 20
```

Better way:

```
if 160 < angle < 200 or not 20 < angle < 340
```

### Vertical

I would say each line with slope angles between [60, 120] or [240, 300] is vertical.

```
if 60< angle < 120 or 240 < angle < 300.
```

Let's assign a limit variable as a threshold so we can change it as will:

for horizontal lines:

```
if (not limit < spl <= 360 - limit) or (180 - limit <= spl < 180 + limit):
```

for vertical lines:

```
if (90 - limit < spl < 90 + limit) or (270 - limit < spl < 270 + limit):
```

The code to check would be:

```
def check_the_line(slope, limit=10):
    if (not limit < spl <= 360 - limit) or (180 - limit <= spl < 180 + limit):
        return "h"
    elif (90 - limit < spl < 90 + limit) or (270 - limit < spl < 270 + limit):
        return "v"
    
    return "o"
```

Let's validate:

```
import math
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3, 1)

limit = 10


def check_the_line(slope, limit=10):
    if (not limit < spl <= 360 - limit) or (180 - limit <= spl < 180 + limit):
        return "h"
    elif (90 - limit < spl < 90 + limit) or (270 - limit < spl < 270 + limit):
        return "v"

    return "o"


for i in range(0, 360, 1):
    x = 10 * math.cos(math.radians(i))
    y = 10 * math.sin(math.radians(i))
    spl = math.degrees(math.atan2(y, x)) % 360

    ax1.plot([0, x], [0, y])
    if check_the_line(spl, limit=limit) == "h":
        ax2.plot([0, x], [0, y])
    elif check_the_line(spl, limit=limit) == "v":
        ax3.plot([0, x], [0, y])

ax1.set_title("All lines")
ax1.set_xlim([-10, 10])
ax1.set_ylim([-10, 10])

ax2.set_title("Horizontal Lines")
ax2.set_xlim([-10, 10])
ax2.set_ylim([-10, 10])

ax3.set_title("Vertical Lines")
ax3.set_xlim([-10, 10])
ax3.set_ylim([-10, 10])
plt.show()
```

[image: The code applied to different lines]

Comment: Your plots are deceiving because the number of pixels per unit is different for the x-axis and the y-axis. It's particularly flagrant in the last plot, which looks like a hourglass as a result of this difference.

Comment: Everyone with a basic knowledge of "How to read a graph" would know to look at the values on the axes. It's not a paper. I'm sorry, but I was not going to put more time/effort to make the graphs rectangular and visually appealing. I hope OP understands the logic.

Comment: Also, your choices of thresholds means you have a 30° tolerance for vertical lines (allowing range 60, 120 around the angle 90), but only a 20° tolerance for horizontal lines (allowing range 160, 200 around the angle 180).

Comment: Those numbers were placeholders. If you could continue to read you would see the threshold is a fixed value of the function (the `limit`). You see I drew lines for each `20 degrees` and unfortunately `90` is not divisible by `20`.

Answer (score 2):

As you know the coordinates of the endpoints, you could simply compute the slope of the line with

```py
slope = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)
```

If the slope is 0, then the line is horizontal, if it's infinity, then the line is vertical.
In practice, you'll rarely have slopes equal to 0 or infinity. So simply put a threshold like:

```py
if abs(slope) < 1:
    print("It's an horizontal line!")
elif abs(slope) > 100:
    print("It's a vertical line!")
else:
    print("It's... a line!")
```

One other simple solution, if you really care only for horizontal and vertical lines, is to compare x values, and y values:

```py
if abs(x1 - x2) < 5:
    print("It's a vertical line!")
elif abs(y1 - y2) < 5:
    print("It's an horizontal line!")
else:
    print("It's... a line!")
```

*Edit: I added the absolute value to the slope comparisons.*

Comment: let's say we have coordinates (5,5) and (50,10), we know its vertical line but slope will be 0.11...

Comment: (x1 = 5, y1 = 5) and (x2 = 50, y2 = 10) gives an almost flat line (horizontal). x values are "horizontal" coordinates, and y values are "vertical" coordinates. If you swapped the coordinate order, just swap the horizontal/vertical categorization

Comment: and if  (x1 = 20, y1 = 40),(x2 = 22.5, y= 10.5) then m = -11.8, but line in almost vertical

Comment: Your choice of thresholds is super weird. A slope of 1 corresponds to a line with an angle of pi/4 (45°) to the horizontal; so, not a horizontal line at all. A slope of 100 corresponds to a line with an angle of 89.4° to the horizontal; so, a very very vertical line.

Comment: Also, in case of a perfectly vertical line, `x2-x1` will be 0, so your python program will crash with a ZeroDivisionError.

Comment: The threshold are set arbitrarily, for the example. Their values depends on what precision you want. Also the division-by-0 problem is known, you can just test if x1 and x2 are equal before computing the slope. And I added the alternative because of this problem. I didn't provided a full working code for his problem, just hints that he might try.